Why are random integers generated by multiplying by MAX_SAFE_INTEGER not evenly distributed between odd and even?
Trying to generate a number using MAX_SAFE_INTEGER I noticed something strange, I'm sure it has to do with the way numbers are stored in JavaScript, but I don't understand what exactly it is.
// Always returns an odd number
Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

// Returns an odd number 75% of the time
Math.floor(Math.random() * (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1))

// Has a 50/50 chance to return odd or even
Math.ceil(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

How can this behavior be explained and what would be the largest integer you can use in Math.floor to get a 50/50 ratio?


let evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
  if (randomNumber % 2 === 0) {
    evenCount++;
  } else {
    oddCount++;
  }
}

console.log("Number of even numbers:", evenCount);
console.log("Number of odd numbers:", oddCount);




Yes me too, I was wrong, but I think I know the answer. Any random fraction between zero and 1 represented as a binary floating point value is inherently a sum of fractional inverse powers of 2. So, 1/2 + 1/16 + 1/256 + 1/4096 etc. Such values are always inverses of even numbers, so multiplying by an odd number (MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is going to get an odd result.

@Pointy Let’s test this. ½ + ¼ = ¾. The inverse of this is 1⅓, which is not an even number. What?

@user3840170 lol I will not be quitting my non-mathematician day job

Interesting question. In node I got 0 even and 10k odd. If I change Math.floor() to Math.ceil() I get 50/50 +/- 1.5%

First, you should multiply by 253 (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) to get all 53 bits from a Math.random implementation that uses the full double precision. 253−1 doesn’t hurt much (it maps both 0 and 2−53 to 0, producing a tiny bias), but it’s better to pick the solution that’s obviously correct.
But then what’s the issue? Well, your original code works fine on Firefox and Safari! It’s just that V8 (i.e. Chrome and derivatives) uses 52 bits instead of 53.


let mostBits = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    const bits = Math.random().toString(2).slice(2).length;
    if (bits > mostBits) {
        mostBits = bits;
    }
}

console.log("Most bits:", mostBits);



(Firefox, Safari)

Most bits: 53

(Chrome)

Most bits: 52

(The reason that you can store 53 bits accurately with a significand with 52 bits of storage is that the integer part is implicitly a 1 that can be scaled to the right place by the exponent, same as why Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is what it is.)
Looking at the relevant part of V8’s implementation, I assume the only reason it does this is for performance – by fixing the exponent to make the range [1, 2), it can insert the random bits directly into the double instead of having to perform a multiplication.

static inline double ToDouble(uint64_t state0) {
  // Exponent for double values for [1.0 .. 2.0)
  static const uint64_t kExponentBits = uint64_t{0x3FF0000000000000};
  uint64_t random = (state0 >> 12) | kExponentBits;
  return base::bit_cast<double>(random) - 1;
}


Why does multiplying a number in the final result’s range by 253−1 and then flooring it always produce an odd number?

(253−1)x = 253 x − x (exactly)

253 x is always even

In order for 253 x − x to round to the exact floating-point value 253 x (and therefore be an even number), x has to be smaller than 253 x’s ULP (unit in the last place) – which it never can be! x’s ULP is 1/253 of the value of its most significant bit, which is ≤ x.


So to answer your question,

what would be the largest integer you can use in Math.floor to get a 50/50 ratio?

At most 252, but I wouldn’t count on Math.random having more than 32 bits of randomness unless you’re only targeting one engine (V8 changed to 52 in 2015, for example), or even on it being good enough randomness for a particular purpose – none of this stuff is in the spec.

This function returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to +0 but strictly less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-defined algorithm or strategy.

You might want to consider implementing a known PRNG in JavaScript and seeding it with strong randomness from crypto.getRandomValues.

Oh cool, I just tested it in Firefox and it works as expected there.
In a way this means MAX_SAFE_INTEGER isn't 100% safe on V8, lol.
I don't necessarily need strong randomness, but I really wanted to know what caused this behavior.
My use case is for generating temporary unique IDs that can't be longer than 16 characters and only contain digits. I might go with a unix timestamp concatenated with 3 random digits. It does make the ID somewhat predictable, but I don't think that would be an issue (we also don't expect to be generating those often)

@Jean-SamuelGirard: Rest assured MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is 100% safe for its actual purpose on V8 (telling you what integers can be safely represented in a number). If you don’t have high performance requirements, I would recommend a package based on crypto.getRandomValues – it’s usually better for the randomness to be “too good” than the alternative.

It's funny, I did some initial "testing" in Firefox (multiplications in the browser console) and originally thought "no it works fine, I'm getting even numbers all the time".  Then I wrote kind-of a similar tester and ran it in Node, and nope, all odd numbers. So this is highly entertaining (and also highly frustrating I'm sure for the OP!).

Ry- highlighted the solution well. I'm just leaving here a working code that brings an equal ratio of even and odd numbers.
The larger the boundary value of random number generation, the higher the probability of the result being even. If you double this value, the ratio will remain equal after many runs.
So here the emphasis remains on fractions due to JavaScript's floating-point number representation.
Math.floor(
  Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER * (2 * Math.random())
);



let evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0, sumMathRandom = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  const mathRandom = 2 * Math.random();
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(
    Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER * (mathRandom)
  );
  if (randomNumber % 2 === 0) {
    evenCount++;
  } else {
    oddCount++;
  }
  sumMathRandom += mathRandom;
}

console.log("Number of even numbers:", evenCount);
console.log("Number of odd numbers:", oddCount);
console.log("Avarage of Math.random:", sumMathRandom / 10000, '- more odd: avg < 1', '- more even: avg > 1');



